# Disable mouse in tag "li"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in doubt how to, disable the mouse over an image that is in such a tag "li".

I managed to disable the click event, but is necessary  an event that even the mouse would go away and there would any action on the tag.

Like a java disable.

Only in jquery or javascript.

Tank's.

Disabling click:

```
$("#btnEmpresarial").removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: show what have you tried .

Comment: show how you disabled for click.

Comment: "I managed to disable the click event, but is necessary an event that even the mouse would go away and there would any action on the tag." Can someone explain?

Comment: This does not require JS or jQuery

Comment: on modern browser there is CSS rule: `pointer-events:none;` maybe what you are looking for

Comment: I doubt you can turn the user's mouse off with code in a page, and for good reason. Even if you could do that, if you disable the mouse when the user hovers on a tag, how are you going to enable it after that?

Comment: @Giovane do you also want to disable click over links inside that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to hide the mouse cursor, you can always use the CSS property cursor in this way:

```
cursor: 'none';
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FhCLP/

---

If you also want to disable any click, you could use jQuery in this way:

```
$('#element').click(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FhCLP/1/

---

Also, as pointed out by @KyleMit, you can even add the property `cursor:not-allowed;` if you want to show another cursor to specify the `not-allowed` state of the cursor.

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FhCLP/2/

Comment: will it disable ?Op want to disable not hide

Comment: On the second fiddle, you might want to change the cursor property from `none` to `cursor:not-allowed;` as is conventionally the case with disabled controls.  As in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XYL8E/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method:

**Unbind:**
  Removes  handlers attached to the elements:

```
$( "#img li").unbind( "hover" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've attached events to the item, [**`e.preventDefault`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) won't work because you're not stopping the *default* action. I think what you want to do is call [**`.unbind()`**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).  Let's say you attached event handlers all the `li` elements in the following **HTML** but you didn't want to fire any events on the second item.

```html
<ul >
    <li>Enabled</li>
    <li class="prevent">Disabled</li>
</ul>
```

Using **jQuery**, you can remove any bindings that have been applied to any items with the `prevent` class

```js
 $('.prevent').unbind();
```

If it improves clarity, you can style your element with the following **CSS**

```css
.prevent {
    cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XYL8E/)